# why can't I define a php array element as an anonymous function?

Tags: php, arrays, function

why doesn't this work?

```
$arr=array(
7,
'h',
function($text){echo $text;}
);

$arr[2]('some text');
```

I want it to echo 'some text' but it says that there is an unexpected T_FUNCTION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous functions have been added in PHP 5.3.0 to my knowledge. This error seems to indicate that the version you're using doesn't support them.

Comment: I found that I can use create_function() instead

Answer (score 2):

Indeed that seems to be the correct answer. I wasn't sure that the function in array syntax would work (even in PHP 5.3.x), so I've just tested it and it does seem to work:

```
<?php
echo phpversion( ) . ": ";
$foo = array( 
    'test' => function( ) {
        return 'This is my test.';
    }
);

echo $foo['test']( );
?>
```

That outputs (on my machine, of course):

> 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7: This is my test.